# Should I use the onCLick={} function in the <Link> or it's surrounding element

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am building a react app and integrating it now with both react router and redux and would like to know if it better code to put my onClick function in my Link or in a surrounding element such as td or div?

or is better to wrap the element in Link?

```
<th id={data.fixture_id + 'box'}>
   <Link to="/fixture" onClick={ e => this.props.getFixture(data.fixture_id, data.league_id) }> 
     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} color="#403F45" id={data.fixture_id} className="bish-move"/>
   </Link>
</th>
```

Comment: your question is unclear. you want to . add in link right? normal div components dont have onclick properties

Comment: yes I want to add in my Links, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to follow the best practices keep you code clean and easy to read as much as possible,so what you can do here:

```
const onClick =  e =>  
     this.props.getFixture(data.fixture_id, data.league_id) 

<th id={data.fixture_id + 'box'}>
   <Link to="/fixture" onClick={onClick}> 
     <FontAwesomeIcon 
         icon={faChevronDown} 
         color="#403F45" 
         id={data.fixture_id}
         className="bish-move"/>
   </Link>
</th>
```

and you can also deconstruct the nested objects values and use them